# slow video frame extraction in openCV -- file format?

Tags: performance, python-2.7, import, codec, opencv3.0

I am importing frames from video, using openCV3 in python2.7. My target file is a 1920x1280 mp4 file (x264 codec); I am loading consecutive frames and displaying them. 
This process is very slow - I receive somewhere between 1 and 2 fps.

I wonder if the problem lies with the video format (or the file size of 4GB...) - videos with lower resolution display at 20fps.

I have tried reformatting the video to use mp4 or mp2 codecs, but see only a small increase in extraction speed. Is openCV known to be slow under certain conditions? Am I using the importing function incorrectly?

Code:

```
import cv2

vid = 'vid.mp4'
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
step_size = 42  # in ms; duration that every single frame is displayed at playback speed

def get_image(time):
    vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, time)
    success, img = vidcap.read()
    return img

for i in range(1, 1000, step_size):  # effectively stepping from frame to frame
    print i
    b = get_image(i)
    cv2.imshow("b", b)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Provided importing runs smoothly enough, I am planning to add image processing steps. Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks,

mondo